# different python versions from the same command prompt in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is to do with calling python from a command prompt in `windows 10` after installing a new version (`3.9` to `3.10`).

When I type (into a `cmd` prompt): `py` i get `Python 3.10.0`.

When I type (into a `cmd` prompt): `python` i get `Python 3.9.6`.

---

So two questions:

1. Why do I get two ***different*** versions when typing `python` compared to `py`?
2. How can I ensure that they point to the same version or how can I select different versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there are two versions of python on your computer. When you want to refer to a particular version of python just do:

`py - version`

---

For example, if you want to reference python 3.10 in cmd, do: `py - 310`

And when you want to reference to 3.9 do: `py - 39`

---

**Make sure you have the correct spacing^**

Comment: to clarify, would this be the same for pip installs to specific versions ?  `py -3.10 -m pip install some_module`

Comment: yh but you have wrong format: py - 310 -m pip install some_module

Comment: space between the dash and 310

Comment: mine worked like this:   `py -3.10 -m pip install some_module`. You answered the question well, so i will mark this as complete.